# action for 'contact form 7'?

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I have a page outside of my standard Wordpress site and I want to use my header and footer on it so it looks like it's part of my site. In my footer, I have a CF7 form that I'm trying to replicate. However, in the action, it says `/#wpcf7-f1-t1-o1` however I'm not sure where that is in the plugins folder. Anybody know? Or is there an alternate action I can put in there?

Answer (score 2):

That action means "post the form back to the website root". Your website root is the very 'top level' of your domain, for example `http://www.example.com/`.

The hash indicates the point in the document to jump to - in this case, I'm betting the ID of the form is `wpcf7-f1-t1-o1`?

You shouldn't need to alter this. Even though the form is on a page outside of WordPress, when the user clicks submit, they'll get sent back to your homepage where the form can be handled.

Comment: I tried leaving it alone and also adding my site url to the front of it `http://mysite.com/#wpcf7-f1-t1-o1` and when I click on submit, the loading gif just keeps spinning.

Comment: Sounds like a JavaScript issue - I'd advise removing any scripts to do with the form. Admittedly, you won't benefit from client-side validation on first submit, but you'll save yourself a lot of headaches!

Answer (score 0):

A possible replacement for that action would be the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] variable. This basically guarantees a post-back to the current page. Just put it right in front of the /# in the action attribute.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>/#wpcf7-f1-t1-o1"...
```

Otherwise, what #wpcf7-f1-t1-o1 is referring to is just the ID of an element on the page to act as an anchor, so when the page loads, it pops right down to that element.